# Sibling directories lost after git stash of current directory

Tags: git, git-stash

Let's say I have this directory structure:

```
project_root
|
+--parent
   |
   +--child
   |
   +--baby_brother
```

`baby_brother` is a new directory, untracked by git.  I also have lots of changes to the files in `child`.  I needed temporary access to the previous versions of the files in `child`, so I figured I'd just stash my changes:

```
cd $project_root/parent/child
git stash push .
```

Then later:

```
cd $project_root/parent/child
git stash pop
```

Now, much to my dismay, `baby_brother` is missing, along with a week's worth of work.  :-(

I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to get my files back?  I suspect the answer is "no".
2. Is this a bug, or did I do something wrong?

I've seen [an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613956/strange-git-case-git-stash-followed-by-git-stash-apply-lost-uncommitted-data) that says it's expected behavior for git to delete untracked files, but for one, it also says this was fixed in 1.7.1.1 (I'm using 2.13.0), and for two, I expected the stash only to affect `child`, since I was in that directory and included a dot at the end of the command to reference the current directory.

---

Here is a quick repro that demonstrates the problem:

```
1 ~ % mkdir project_root
2 ~ % cd project_root
3 project_root % mkdir parent
4 project_root % touch parent/file
5 project_root % mkdir parent/child
6 project_root % touch parent/child/file2
7 project_root % git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/pdaddy/project_root/.git/
8 project_root % git add .
9 project_root % git commit -m 'Get it in git'
[master (root-commit) 2d0872c] Get it in git
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 parent/child/file2
 create mode 100644 parent/file
10 project_root % mkdir parent/baby_brother
11 project_root % touch parent/baby_brother/file3
12 project_root % touch parent/file4
13 project_root % touch file5
14 project_root % comment="As it turns out, file4 and file5 will be deleted, too."
15 project_root % tree $PWD
/home/pdaddy/project_root
|-- file5
`-- parent
    |-- baby_brother
    |   `-- file3
    |-- child
    |   `-- file2
    |-- file
    `-- file4

3 directories, 3 files
16 project_root % echo 'some changes' >> parent/child/file2
17 project_root % cd parent/child
18 child % git stash push .
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 2d0872c Get it in git
19 project_root % tree ~/project_root
/home/pdaddy/project_root
`-- parent
    |-- child
    |   `-- file2
    `-- file

2 directories, 2 files
20 child % git stash pop
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file2

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (80e41d0ed1f2b0a085d4f5ca3a38833a18873f98)
21 child % tree ~/project_root
/home/pdaddy/project_root
`-- parent
    |-- child
    |   `-- file2
    `-- file

2 directories, 2 files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested my repro example with git's [next](https://github.com/git/git/tree/next) branch (v2.14.0.rc0), and the problem didn't present itself, so I guess this is a bug, and someone has committed a fix.